# Apache2 cause too much memory and cpu

Tags: apache2

I run an apache2 with PH with 2GB of RAM. I have added a swap space already. My server frequently frezzes and it takes more than 100% of CPU. What should i do to prevent this?

[This is top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efuMH.jpg)

Comment: The few details you have provided barely begins to describe the problem. Please provide a description of the application load (web server requests per second), httpd configuration relevant to performance, and basic performance metrics for storage and network performance:  https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/linux-performance-analysis-in-60-000-milliseconds-accc10403c55   At first glance just from top, almost certainly you are under memory pressure given swap used. And swap disk is slow so tasks pile up.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will wait for the server to freeze and post the data here